# Need to build a super long gripper arm (reacher tool, pick up tool)

Tags: tools, extension

I need to build super long, super-extended gripper arm tool (also called a reacher, pick up tool, reach grabber, trash picker). Something that combines the two pictures below.

It needs to be at least 15' (fifteen feet) long.

The longest I can find for sale is [this 10' (ten foot) long](https://www.homedepot.com/p/E-Z-Reacher-120-in-PRO-Folding-Series-Black-Pick-Up-Tool-120PF/203221308).

Your suggestions needed!

[image] [image]

Comment: The essential issue with trying to make something like that extensible is that it uses a simple wire-pull to actuate. If you could run 15ft of wire, you'd always have to have it fully extended to work. That would also cause issues of how the wire folds back up when not extended.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Perhaps there are other solutions as well.

Comment: Not exactly sure how this is [diy.se].

Comment: Vacuum pick-up is easily extended, depending on its suitability for what you are grabbing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about home improvement.

Comment: It was on lifehacks before, it's better suited over there I reckon.

Comment: @Tetsujin a telescopic tree pruner works by pulling the string directly.  You could either do that or have the string attach to the trigger with an adjustable anchor (clamp, screw, etc.)

Comment: Use cases, modifications and combinations of tools seems on-topic to me.  In general, that is.    Not every question will probe new frontiers of knowledge.   There are some nice tools you can build with a stick, a wire hanger, and some tape and I think good ideas belong here.   We don't close mediocre but on topic questions, do we?

Answer (score 7):

It turns out there is a cheesy made-for-TV solution to your problem, whatever that problem may be: **YOU WANT THE [NO LADDER PRO MAX](https://youtu.be/n7zVyhlzS5Q?t=54) !!!!!!!**

But if you're not the 9-easy-installments type of person, just **tape** any gripper wand (like the one you show) to any pole and tie a **string** to the trigger.

If "tape and string" feels too much like a cliché for a botch job, you can use hose clamps and nylon rope.  But I suspect the nature of your real problem is such that tape and string is probably poetically suitable. :)

You can buy this ready-made in the form of a tree pruner attachment for the extendible pole, if you don't mind the grippy part being sharp.  Or you could remove the blade.

[image]